Error during updating Ubuntu - WSL
I am trying to update/install some packages using sudo apt on Ubuntu in WSL. This is the error I get -
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't link /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libnvoptix_loader.so.1 to libnvoptix.so.1
What could be the reason and what can be done to rectify it? This error occurs on both 24.04 and 22.04 LTS versions

This is likely relevant

@Ramhound I did look at it and similar other posts, but none of them mention my exact error. So, I did not want to meddle with the library files and mess up installation completely

You will have to rule out that the answer to that question is not relevant to your problem.
